# How does Python handle equality checking?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bit-manipulation, logical-operators

```
>>> l=[(i,j,k) for i in {-4,-2,1,2,5,0} for j in {-4,-2,1,2,5,0} for k in {-4,-2,1,2,5,0} if i+j+k==0 if i==0 & j==0 & k==0]
>>> l
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 2, -2), (0, -2, 2)]
```

The above Python 3 code finds triples(i,j,k) such that i+j+k=0 and all elements are 0.So the answer should be (0,0,0).

But the answer came was [(0, 0, 0), (0, 2, -2), (0, -2, 2)]

After a bit of searching I found that the problem lies in the use of `&` instead of `and`.I understand that `and` is a logical operator and `&` is a bitwise operator.

But I'm not able to figure out why I got the answers I got by using`&`.

How does Python3 handle equality checking operation?

Comment: I don't understand what this has to do with equality checking.

Comment: I'm a newbie here. So please edit the title if you feel it is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your spacing in

```
i==0 & j==0 & k==0
```

is misleading you; `==` has lower precedence than `&` so the calculation is actually

```
i == 0&j == 0&k == 0
```

Because `0&anything`is 0, this becomes

```
i == 0 == 0 == 0
```

which is the same as

```
i == 0
```

because Python chains comparisons (such as `4 < x < 10`).

Therefore

```
[(i,j,k) for i in {-4,-2,1,2,5,0} for j in {-4,-2,1,2,5,0} for k in {-4,-2,1,2,5,0} if i+j+k==0 if i==0 & j==0 & k==0]
```

will give every `(i,j,k)` tuple where `i+j+k = 0` and `i = 0`, so where `i = 0` and `j = -k`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this: `if i==0 & j==0 & k==0`.

Solution:

```
>>> l=[(i,j,k) for i in {-4,-2,1,2,5,0} for j in {-4,-2,1,2,5,0} for k in {-4,-2,1,2,5,0} if i+j+k==0 and (i==0 and j==0 and k==0)]
>>> l
[(0, 0, 0)]
```

Comment: Sir finally I did it using `and`. But I wanted to know the reason for this discrepancy in output.